# Mouse Problems with Ubuntu in Hyper-V

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

I have installed Ubuntu in one of my virtual machines of Hyper-V.

Mouse doesn't work in the guest operating system and I get the following exception.

```
[Window Title]
Virtual Machine Connection

[Main Instruction]
Mouse not captured in Remote Desktop session.

[Content]
The mouse is available in a Remote Desktop session when integration services are installed in the guest operating system. For more information, search on 'integration services' in Help.

[ ] Please don't show me this again  [OK]
```

Can someone guide me if you have tried it? If it is possible to make it work, please let me know.
Please do consider that I am very new to Ubuntu and linux environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synthetic Mouse Support is not included in the Hyper-V Linux integration components.  There are references in the older, separate builds of the integration components (2.1) for the Citrix Project Satori Web site at http://www.xen.org/products/satori.html

Unfortunately, the setup for these drivers do not work with the current Hyper-V integration components that are included with the Linux kernel.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=877096#p877096

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following blog post - it is for Ubuntu 10.10 server specifically, though the steps illustrated should get you most of the way there, if not completely:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/10/21/installing-ubuntu-server-10-10-on-hyper-v.aspx

The article recommends adding the following four lines to the end of the `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` file:

```
hv_vmbus
hv_storvsc
hv_blkvsc
hv_netvsc
```

Save your changes and issue the command `update-initramfs –u` and reboot. With any luck you should be up and working.

Comment: Hmmm... But will it actually resolve the mouse integration issue as none of the additions appear to address that?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu does not appear to be an OS that supports the "Enlightenment" virtualization support that is "preferred" with Hyper-V. It's not alone as most earlier version of Windows also fall into the same situation. If you search around, there are some hacks/guides which may help.